# android accessibilityNodeInfo and change accessibility role issue

Tags: android, talkback

If I want to let TalkBack read my custom view as a button role, I can change AccessibilityNodeInfo by setting setClassName method.

By the way,

1. There are two buttons.
2. Button A is selected with `setSelected` true method.
3. If I doubletap button b, `B` is selected and `A` is unselected.
4. I want to let `TalkBack` read these two buttons as `RadioButton`, not button.

Because originally the two buttons are not real button and the function is radio button.

Of course developer should change their button class to RadioButton, they can't do this.

But if I use `AccessibilityNodeInfo`'s `setClassName` method, it doesn't work.

I think `setClassName` method is only working if my view is custom view or has no specific class itself.

But in this case, I want to change accessibility role from button to radio button.

In this case, how should I apply?